# Select a string between two strings

Tags: sql, string, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a `string` that always looks like

> PROJECT CODE:  CUSTOMER PO #:  ORDER #:  N2:  BUCKET #: OKL-1335-081417-A1 RUN #: OKL-1335-081417-A BUILD #: 1 NOTES:

How would I select just the Bucket Number out of this

> (OKL-1335-081417-A1)

Basically everything `between` 'Bucket #:' and 'Run'. Below is what I tried, but  that is erroring out with the message "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.":

```
substring(oe_hdr_notepad.note,charindex('Bucket #:',oe_hdr_notepad.note)+len('Bucket #:'),charindex('RUN',oe_hdr_notepad.note)-charindex('Bucket #:',oe_hdr_notepad.note)-len('Bucket #:'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just run this query in my SQL Management studio.

```
declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql = 'PROJECT CODE:  CUSTOMER PO #:  ORDER #:  N2:  BUCKET #: OKL-1335-081417-A1 RUN #: OKL-1335-081417-A BUILD #: 1 NOTES:'

select substring(@sql,charindex('Bucket #:',@sql)+len('Bucket #:')+1,charindex('RUN',@sql)-charindex('Bucket #:',@sql)-len('Bucket #:')-1)
```

I got the next output:

```
OKL-1335-081417-A1 

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Your problem could be with `oe_hdr_notepad.note`.
I suggest printing it out to make sure it's the same string you have posted.

If the length of the string is always the same, you can hardcode the length of the third parameter in your `SUBSTRING` like:

```
select substring(@sql,charindex('Bucket #:',@sql)+len('BUCKET #:')+1,18)
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(
    MyString 
        FROM (POSITION('BUCKET #: ' IN MyString) + 10) -- Starting point
        FOR ( -- Calculate How many characters to grab
            POSITION(' RUN #: ' IN MyString) - 
            (POSITION('BUCKET #: ' IN MyString) + 10)
        )
    )
FROM (
SELECT 'PROJECT CODE: CUSTOMER PO #: ORDER #: N2: BUCKET #: OKL-1335-081417-A1 RUN #: OKL-1335-081417-A BUILD #: 1 NOTES:' AS MyString
) src
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, how about a little XML

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (id int,note varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'PROJECT CODE:  CUSTOMER PO #:  ORDER #:  N2:  BUCKET #: OKL-1335-081417-A1 RUN #: OKL-1335-081417-A BUILD #: 1 NOTES: ')

Select A.ID
      ,Bucket = convert(xml,'<x>'+replace(replace(note,'RUN #:','</x><x>'),'BUCKET #:','</x><x>')+'</x>').value('/x[2]','varchar(100)')
 From @YourTable A
```

**Returns**

```
ID   Bucket
1    OKL-1335-081417-A1
```